# Google Chrome save language layout per page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, language

I use Ubuntu 17 with Google Chrome and it doesn't save language per tabs. 
Is it any way to make Google Chrome save language per tab?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible in Chrome in the way you would like.
It is standard practice in most Firefox-derived browsers,
but not in Chrome.

You may use the following extensions to improve your browsing :

[**Google Input Tools**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-input-tools/mclkkofklkfljcocdinagocijmpgbhab?hl=en)

> Switch to typing in a different language with the click of the mouse, and switch back just as easily. The Google Input Tools extension provides virtual keyboards for over 90 languages, full IMEs or direct transliteration for over 30 different scripts, and handwriting input for over 40 languages.

[**Quick Language Switcher**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-language-switcher/pmjbhfmaphnpbehdanbjphdcniaelfie)

> Small Extension which allows to quickly switch the Accept-Language header in all web requests. This allows for testing localization issues.

These extensions do not do exactly what you are asking for,
but may help to alleviate the problem.